# change css dynamically according to size of parent iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

My partner sites embed my website using an iframe. I recently change my website and it is now longer than what my partner sites have allocated in their iframe (and they have all set `scrolling=no`.

Given that I can't change my partner sites, I am trying to change my own site now so that everything still works. I noticed that I can add `<div style='width:325px;height:400px;overflow:scroll'>` as long as width and height is the same as the parent iframe.

**Is there a way I can dynamically obtain width and height of parent iframe so that I can apply it onto my own site? Or can I use viewport to determine how big the parent container is?**

```html
<iframe srcdoc="
<html><body>
<div style='width:325px;height:400px;overflow:scroll'>
<h1>Hello,<b>world1</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world2</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world3</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world4</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world5</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world6</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world7</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world8</b>.</h1><br />
</div></body></html>" 
scrolling="no" width=325px height=400px>

</iframe>
```

Comment: There's no css like children > parent and you're not in the same origin anyway, going outside of an iframe would be pretty amazing technology tbh

Comment: I don't think this will work if the iframe is cross-origin, but try accessing the `parent` from within the iframe like so:

`parent.document.body.clientHeight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use viewport width and height: `width:100vw` `height:100vh`

Snippet:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="
<html><body>
<div style='width:100vw;height:100vh;overflow:scroll'>
<h1>Hello,<b>world1</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world2</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world3</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world4</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world5</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world6</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world7</b>.</h1><br /><h1>Hello,<b>world8</b>.</h1><br />
</div></body></html>" 
scrolling="no" width=325px height=400px>

</iframe>
```

Comment: oh nice, let me go try it on my actual code tmr! thanks so much i really hope this works!